# DateTime("2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00") conversion to local date time with offset value

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset, date-conversion

I get the datetime content in the below string format with offset time value from the source system.

**2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00**

Where i want to convert that into local date time using the offset value.I tried the below, but not getting the expected result.

```
DateTime date = new DateTime("2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00");
```

*-->output ==* **2019-02-16T02:00:00.000Z** (the hour is decreased instead of increasing)

```
DateTime date = new DateTime("2019-02-16T10:00:00-08:00");
```

*-->output ==* **2019-02-16T18:00:00.000Z** (the hour is increased instead of decreasing).

is there any simple way to the expected output?
Note: I am using Java 1.7

Comment: Can't you use `java.time`, especially `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`?

Comment: Call the method that returns time as milliseconds since EPOCH, then apply your offset to the milliseconds and then convert the milliseconds back to a date.

Comment: `10:00` in zone `+08:00` is `02:00` in zone `Z (+00:00)`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using Joda Time?

Comment: That `+08:00` etc. is _not_ the offset to be added but the time zone's offset that _has already been added_, so as TiiJ7 already stated `10:00+08:00` is the same as `02:00+00:00` and `10:00-08:00` is the same as `18:00+00:00`. (`00:00` is the UTC offset which `Z` also refers to).

Comment: When using Java 1.7, all other things being equal most would still prefer [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) over Joda-Time.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct. To get the time in your local time zone:

```
    DateTime date = new DateTime("2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00");
    DateTime dateTimeInLocalTimeZone = date.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
    System.out.println(dateTimeInLocalTimeZone);
```

On my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone I got

> 2019-02-16T03:00:00.000+01:00

As has been said in the comments, `+08:00` is the offset that *has already been added* compared to UTC time. So your string denoted the same point in time as `2019-02-16T02:00:00+00:00`. It may also be written as `2019-02-16T02:00:00Z` since `Z` (pronounced “Zulu”) means UTC.

### java.time and ThreeTen Backport

If you are not already tied to Joda-Time, you may prefer to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The code is similar:

```
    OffsetDateTime sourceDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00");
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInLocalTimeZone = sourceDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

> 2019-02-16T03:00+01:00[Europe/Copenhagen]

### Question: Can I use java.time on Java 1.7?

> Note: I am using Java 1.7

No big problem, java.time just requires at least **Java 6**. I have run the above code on jdk1.7.0_79.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do that :

```
String dt =  "2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00";
ZonedDateTime zd = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-02-16T10:00:00+08:00");
System.out.println(zd.toLocalDateTime().plusSeconds(zd.getOffset().getTotalSeconds()));
```

Output

```
2019-02-16T18:00
```